# Scanner No Line Found Exception

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I am getting the following exception.

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

I got this error while writing a larger program which needed to read from a text file, and so decided to do a test.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("restrictions.txt");
String s1 = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(s1);
```

And I still get the exception.  I have a text file in the same folder as the class called restrictions.txt which has text in it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried the same thing with scan.next() instead of scan.nextLine() and got this exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?  Try System.out.println( file.getAbsolutePath() + " " + file.exists() ) and make sure it's there.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the file exists, the Scanner initializes without an exception, and I've tried making it via NetBeans and via the file browser, but I'll check anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new File("restrictions.txt") will look for the file in the "Start dir" of your app - if you're using Eclipse, it's probably the root of your project.

To open the file next to your class, you can use the Scanner constructor which accepts an InputStream that you get by

```
YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("restrictions.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `if(in.hasNextLine())` before calling `in.nextLine()`. Otherwise for last line it will thrown Line not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

[Javadoc for Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Do you need to specify a line ending so it knows what a line is?

Comment: I've been using scanner for a while and have never had to do that, but it's possible.  However, I tried the same thing with scan.next() instead of scan.nextLine() and got this exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Would the input file have different line endings because it was modified on a different OS or editor? Can you share a snippet from the input file, preferably showing line endings?