# Java: Can not load a properties file. Why?

Tags: java, file, properties, properties-file

I am trying to load a properties file.
I have the properties file **in the same directory** as the class that I am trying to load it.
Example:

```
package com.classes.internal;   
public class ClassA {  

    private static String PFILE = "config.properties";  


    private static void methodA(){  
    //do stuff  
        Properties properties = null;  
        try{  
            properties = new Properties();  
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(PFILE));  
            //properties.load(new ClassA().getClass().getResourceAsStream(PFILE)); --> Does not work either   

        }catch(Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  


    }
```

Also `config.properties` file is in com\classes\internal dir

But I get a `FileNotFoundException` or `java.lang.NullPointerException` (if using the commented out line instead of the first)

What am I doing wrong here? What am I missunderstanding?

Comment: Where is properties file relative to your classpath ?

Comment: It is in the same directory as `ClassA`

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688710/scanner-no-line-found-exception/7689102#7689102

Answer (score 2):

The file needs to be in the directory you're executing from, not the directory where the class file is.

So if you have the directory structure

> Project/com/classes/internal

and you run the command

```
Project$ java com.classes.internal.SomeClass
```

Your JVM will look for the "config.properties" file in the "Project" directory.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this.But then what is the meaning of `getClass().getResourceAsStream` etc?

Comment: `getClass().getResourceAsStream` is looking for the file in the folder where the source file for the current class is stored. Try doing `System.out.println(new ClassA().getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));` by placing the `config.properties` file in the folder as stated before.

Answer (score 0):

I think your program work directory not in com\classes\internal. Try to pass this relative path:

```
com\classes\internal\config.properties
```

or absolute path. 
You can obtain current working directory like this

```
String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
    "/com/classes/internal/" + PFILE));
```

Comment: There is no `this`.I am in a `static` method

Comment: ..and what happened when you used the earlier form, with the altered location string?  Note that I'm not in the mood for playing '20 questions' - it pays to use a little initiative when offered answers.

Answer (score 0):

The line below will load file relative to working directory (in FrankieTheKneeMan example, the "Project" folder. If you are running your code in Tomcat, it is quite likely from $Tomcat/bin/):

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream(PFILE));
```

And for the line below, it is loading file relative to your classpath. So "config.properties" refer to directory that contain your "com" folder, instead of "com/classes/internal/".

```
properties.load(new ClassA().getClass().getResourceAsStream(PFILE));
```

So you need to decide on whether to load from classpath, or from working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Example. I'm using eclipse project structure, I hope you get the picture anyway:

```
//File in Project/src/com/classes/internal/config.properties
InputStream in = ClassA.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
Properties p = new Properties();
try {
   p.load(in);
} catch(IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In case you decide to put your file outside package:

```
//File in Project/src/config.properties
InputStream in = ClassA.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Note that `getResourceAsStream` file has to be included in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **config** package in the source folder directly and place the *config.properties* file in it. On building the application, it will go to /WEB-INF/classes/config/config.properties

You can then use the following code to access the properties file -

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String propFileName = "/config/config.properties";

    InputStream input = null;

    input = ClassA.class.getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
    prop.load(input);
```