# Is a scan line escaping?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been doing a small project for class, it runs perfectly without problems but when pitted against the class's auto testers it gives back 2 No line found errors. Asking the course's staff they say it's probably because I'm trying to scan a line when none exist, but I tried printing all my scans and didn't discover anything like that.
That's all the scans I have in my code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence;
    int choice;

    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
    sentence = sc.nextLine();

    printMenu(); // calls a function to print the menu.

    // gets the require action
    System.out.println("Choose option to execute:");
    choice = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
```

(I tried with and without the last sc.nextLine)

```
static void replaceStr(String str)
{
    String oldWord, newWord;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get the strings
    System.out.println("String to replace: ");
    oldWord = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("New String: ");
    newWord = in.nextLine();

    // replace
    str = str.replace(oldWord, newWord);
    System.out.println("The result is: " + str);
    in.close();
}
static void removeNextChars(String str)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String remStr; // to store the string to replace
    String tmpStr = ""; //the string we are going to change.
    int i; // to store the location of indexStr

    // gets the index
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    remStr = in.nextLine();
    i=str.indexOf(remStr);

    in.close(); // bye bye

    if (i < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("The result is: "+str);
        return;
    }

    // Build the new string without the unwanted chars.
    /* code that builds new string */

    str = tmpStr;
    System.out.println("The result is: "+str);
}
```

Any idea how a line can leak here?

Comment: Did you look at [Scanner No Line Found Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688710/scanner-no-line-found-exception)

Comment: Richard - The code doesn't give me errors and work as expected. It's the class's auto tester that say "No line found", without going into any further details. And yeah, i did look at that already. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Probably a [No Such Element exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html). When / how does your program continue / stop reading input? Is there a `while(...){...}` loop or something?

Comment: I gave here all the scans in my program... no whiles are used and nothing special.

Comment: in witch environment(linux/windo/...) program is running. Is that same environment that you tested and auto tester doing

Comment: You need to show us the **actual error message**. You need to indicate which line is causing this error to occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the problem. You are using `in.close();` at multiple places(last statement in `replaceStr` method and around the middle in `removeNextChars` method). When you close the scnaner using `close()` method, it closes your `InputStream (System.in)` as well. That InputStream can't be reopened with-in your program.

`public void close() throws IOException --> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream. The general contract of close is that it closes the input stream. A closed stream cannot perform input operations and **cannot be reopened.**`

**Any read attempts after the scanner close will result into exception NoSuchElementException.**

Please close your scanner only once, when your program is done.

EDIT: Scanner Closing/usage:

In yout main function:

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   ....
   .....
   replaceStr(Scanner sc, String str);
   .....
   ....
   removeNextChars(Scanner sc ,String str);
   ....
   ....
   //In the end
   sc.close();


static void replaceStr(Scanner in, String str){
  //All the code without scanner instantiation and closing
  ...
}

static void removeNextChars(Scanner in, String str){
  //All the code without scanner instantiation and closing
  ...
}
```

You should be all good.

Comment: oh, Then how do I use scanners inside functions?

Comment: @Nescio Just don't close them

Comment: Just pass the scanner as argument in your functions. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - I also thought re-creating the `Scanner` shouldn't cause this problem - but I wrote a sample program and it throws the error! From [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html): "When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface."

Comment: @Nescio: I updated the answer with sample statements showing how to deal with scanner across the functions and how to close it. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, that did seem to solve it, and it looks like a better way of handling code anyway. Still new to Java :p Though it does seem weird that the program ran flawlessly on my computer and failed on their tester, as far as I know we both use linux with the same Java sdk

Comment: @Nescio: I am just suspecting that both functions may not have been called in your local test scenario. The functions may be being called on some condition. Issue will not arise until both the functions are called. Please let me know, if this is not the case.

Comment: Yep, that's probably it, my program gives a choice and only utilizes one of the functions. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Nescio: Good to know that I was able to help without knowing much about your program conditions :)