# Reading from .txt file returns "No line Found"

Tags: java, exception, special-characters, netbeans-7, java.util.scanner

I've made a GUI and a button.
My code looks like this:

```
private void jButtonSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
try {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("persontest.txt"));
  while(scan.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  System.out.println("File not found" + ex.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Some error" + e.getMessage());
}
```

persontest.txt contains the following text:

> 1. What do I contribute with when working in team work:
>      a. I come up with new ideas
>      b. I follow-up on things because I'm basically
>      thorough
>      c. I assess what is realistic and workable
>      d. I advocate alternative approaches objectively and unbiased

When trying to run I get "Some error No line found"
I tried removing all special characters from the text and I could read it, so I tried adding "UTF-8" to my scanner in this manner.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("persontest.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

However this does not seem to do anything. I still get "No line found".
If this question has been asked before excuse me, I did a thorough search, but I either could not comprehend the question asked or the answer provided in context to my problem.
I changed my scanner to bufferedreader per Troubleshoot and Harshas example and it will now read the text even with special chars, however it won't display them correctly. I just get square boxes. It's a minor problem.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688710/scanner-no-line-found-exception - Try its answer

Comment: What is you directory structure? How you run application (from eclipse, command line)?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is an answer to my question. I can read the text fine without " . ", " ' " and " - ", and any other .txt file I have tried with this code. But this .txt gives me this error. - I run the file trough Netbeans. It's "most likely" not my directoty structure that's broken, since I can use any other text in the document and it works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure *persontest.txt* is in your main project folder, and not a sub-folder of that, as it will not find it otherwise.

I recommend using a BufferedReader to read it line by line. Here's how:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("persontest.txt"));
String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

It's good practice to check that the line isn't empty along with checking it isn't equal to null. For example, if a line was equal to **\t** it would be classed as empty, but not as null.

Answer (score 1):

If persontest.txt is in classpath (i.e. inside jar or source folder) you can use:

```
YourClass.class.getClassloader().getResourceAsStream("persontest.txt")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply do this using

```
    try {

        String line;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("persontest.txt"));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

if you need to do it with a Scanner you can try using

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("persontest.txt");
```